# Python ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

Tags: python, csv, datetime, strptime, strftime

I have the following error:

> line 73, in formatFile
>   outRow.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(row[5],'%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
>   ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

Script below:

```
import datetime

  def formatFile(fname):
    print(fname)

       formattedFile=open(workingFolder() + '\\FormattedFile.csv','w')
       writer = csv.writer(formattedFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,lineterminator='\n')
       writer.writerow(["Name","Unit","Unit Size","Other","Note","Mode Here"])

       with open(fName) as f:
          reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')    
          next(reader)
          for row in reader:
              outRow=[]


              outRow.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(row[5],'%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

              #other script here that works well as part of a for loop

              print(outRow)
              writer.writerow(outRow)
```

The date I have is in a .csv file as a text looks like this: "11/19/2017"
I want it in this format: "2017-11-19". Not sure what I am doing wrong?

I have read this about 5 times and still unsure why it is giving me the error:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Example of csv file here:

```
"Name","Unit","Unit Size","Other","Mode","Date" 
"name here","unit here","YYY x YY","Note","Mode here","11/19/2017"
"name here","unit here","YYY x YY","Note","Mode here","11/20/2017"
"name here","unit here","YYY x YY","Note","Mode here","12/04/2017"
```

Comment: can you share a sample from your fName?

Comment: Use a debugger to find out the value on the failing line

Comment: Most likely you have some issue with your data source.

Comment: Are there spaces around the date in the CSV file?

Comment: No spaces around the CSV file. 
If I remove these lines the script works perfectly fine so I don't think there is a problem with the data source.
Can you suggest a debugger to use please Antti?

Comment: You have other errors, at least in the supplied code as in problems with indentations and the placement of `outRow`. It should be before the `for` loop, because in your current case it'll be emptied for each row and you'll keep at the end only the last date.
Also, provide a sample of your file as you were requested.

Comment: just print the `row` too... this way don't need the debugger as it will show you on which value it's failing.... btw, the error message tells you that the value you're getting is an empty string

Comment: Sample file has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a total row at the bottom of the list which was crashing the file... Corrected with this:

```
for row in reader:
    if "Total" not in row:
       #script here
    else:
        break
```